# Как поменять местами дробную и целую части числа?

Tags: python

> Дано вещественное число вида nnn.ddd (по три разряда в целой и дробной части). Поменять местами дробную и целую части числа.

---

Я так вижу её на питоне. Подскажите, правильно или нет. Почему-то не идёт.

```
n=float(input())
print((n*1000)%1000+int(n)/1000)
```

Comment: Где у вас возникли затруднения в решении задачи?

Comment: в написании этой задачи на питоне. Только начали изучать. не совсем понимаю этот язык. На паскале написала, а питон не идёт    Var r:real;
Begin
write('vvedite chislo r vida (nnn.ddd):');
readln(r);
writeln (frac(r)*1000+int(r)/1000:3:3);
End.

Comment: n=float(input())
print((n*1000)%1000+int(n)/1000)

Comment: не знаю, у меня этот код корректно работает

Comment: @diraria: попробуйте: `001.001` с формулой в вопросе.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы избежать проблем с тем [как float представлены в компьютере](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), работайте со строками напрямую:

```
s = input().strip()
print(*s.partition('.')[::-1], sep='')
```

Пример ввода:

```
543.210
```

[Вывод](https://ideone.com/zP0avY):

```
210.543
```

Если хотите как с числом работать, то можно использовать класс, который десятичные цифры использует внутри для хранения чисел:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> d = Decimal('543.210')
>>> (d%1)*1000+Decimal(int(d))/1000
Decimal('210.543')
```

Результаты обоих методов совпадают с точностью до лидирующих нулей в начале целой части.

Comment: Спасибо, справилась.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 123.001

'{0:07.3f}'.format((x - int(x)) * 1000 + int(x) / 1000)
# '001.123'

float('{0:07.3f}'.format((x - int(x)) * 1000 + int(x) / 1000))
# 1.123
```

Comment: Спасибо за активное участие в моей проблеме.